# rigid body poisson bracket

Tags: classical-mechanics, symplectic-geometry

I have trouble to understand the definition of the rigid body poisson brackets. 
In the book of Marsden and Ratiu "Introduction to Mechanics and Symmetry", Chapter 10.1, they introduce the Poisson bracket as follows: 
Let $\Pi \in \mathbb{R}^3 \simeq \mathfrak{so(3)}$, the Lie algebra of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$. The gradients of the functions $F,G \in C^\infty((\mathbb{R}^3)^*,\mathbb{R})$ are evaluated at the point $\Pi$. The bracket has form 
$$\{F,G\}=-\langle \Pi, \nabla F(\Pi) \times \nabla G (\Pi)\rangle$$ 
A few pages later, they introduce a Casimir function w.r.t. the rigid body Poisson bracket: $$C(\Pi)=\frac12 (\Pi_1^2+\Pi_2^2+\Pi_3^2).$$ This function fullfills the property that 
$$\{C,G\}= -\langle \Pi, \nabla C(\Pi) \times \nabla G (\Pi)\rangle=- \langle  \Pi, \Pi \times \nabla G (\Pi)\rangle=-\langle \nabla G,\Pi \times \Pi\rangle =0$$
but this means the Cartesian coordinates are $ \Pi_1, \Pi_2, \Pi_3$, because the gradient is a  derivation w.r.t. the Cartesian coordinates. But this means $\Pi$ must have the form $\Pi=(\Pi_1,\Pi_2,\Pi_3)^T$, otherwise the argumentation of the Casimir function wouldn´t work. But this means $\Pi$ isn't an arbitrary point in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but later $\Pi$ is a position vector of a point on an arbitrary sphere.

I hope you understand my problem. I would be glad if someone could help me.

Comment: At least to me, it's not at all clear what your problem is. The point $\Pi$ is indeed an arbitary point in $\mathbb{R^3}$, and the Poisson bracket takes two functions of $\Pi$ and produces a new function of $\Pi$. The function $C$ is special, since the bracket between $C$ and any other function is zero. This has the consequence that $C$ is a constant of motion with respect to any Hamiltonian system for this Poisson bracket. So if $\Pi(t)$ is a solution to such a system, the value of $C(\Pi(t))$ will be constant in time, i.e., $\Pi(t)$ will remain on the sphere that it started on.

Comment: My problem is, that a gradient is a derivation of the cartesian coordinates and my gradient of C  is a derivation w.r.t. $\Pi_1,\Pi_2$ and $\Pi_3$. How can $\Pi$ be an arbitrary point and the cartesian coordinates? The function C was chosen to illustrate my problem. I thought, that if i want an arbitrary point in the basis of $\Pi$ i would take something like $a\Pi_1+b\Pi_2+c\Pi_3$, with a,b,c$\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: What??? I still can't understand what you're trying to say, but maybe you're confusing coordinates and basis vectors. What we mean when we say that $(\Pi_1,\Pi_2,\Pi_3)$ are (Cartesian) coordinates is that the position of an arbitrary point can be described by the values of the variables $\Pi_1$, $\Pi_2$ and $\Pi_3$, and that the gradient of a function $F(\Pi_1,\Pi_2,\Pi_3)$ is the vector field $(\partial F/\partial \Pi_1,\partial F/\partial \Pi_2,\partial F/\partial \Pi_3)$. There are no basis vectors explicitly written out in this notation.